# Always get the Unique ID and release it for reuse

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

```
ExecutorService service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 1000L,
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10, true), new 
    ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

**Problem Statement is:-**

Each thread uses `unique ID` between `1 and 1000` and program has to run for `60 minutes or more`, In my `run method` I was getting `id as zero` few times when I did `(if(id==0))` check and I put the breakpoint under that loop, I don't know why? As the availableExistingIds has value in the range between 1 and 1000, then I don't know from where this `zero is coming in my id`?

```
class IdPool {
    private final LinkedList<Integer> availableExistingIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public IdPool() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            availableExistingIds.add(i);
        }
    }

    public synchronized Integer getExistingId() {
        return availableExistingIds.removeFirst();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseExistingId(Integer id) {
        availableExistingIds.add(id);
    }
}


class ThreadNewTask implements Runnable {
    private IdPool idPool;
    private int id;

    public ThreadNewTask(IdPool idPool) {
        this.idPool = idPool;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
        id = idPool.getExistingId();
    //Anything wrong here?  
                if(id==0) {
        System.out.println("Found Zero");
        }
        someMethod(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
        idPool.releaseExistingId(id);
        }
    }

// This method needs to be synchronized or not?
    private synchronized void someMethod(Integer id) {
        System.out.println("Task: " +id);
// and do other calcuations whatever you need to do in your program
    }
}
```

Below is the main class from which program is starting-

```
public class TestingPool {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int size = 10;
        int durationOfRun = 60;
        IdPool idPool = new IdPool();   
        // create thread pool with given size
        ExecutorService service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(size, size, 500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(size), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()); 

        // queue some tasks
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun * 60 * 1000L);

        // Running it for 60 minutes
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
            service.submit(new ThreadNewTask(idPool));
        }

        // wait for termination        
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS); 
    }
}
```

**Update:-**

I was thinking to use ArrayBlockingQueue here so that instead of crashing when there are no available ids, it waits for one to become available. Can anyone suggest me how can I use it here?

Code Change after implementation of BlockingQueue.

```
public void run() {
    System.err.println(command.getDataCriteria());
    if(command.getDataCriteria().equals(PDSLnPConstants.DATA_CRITERIA_PREVIOUS)) {
    try {
        System.out.println(command.getDataCriteria());
        // Getting existing id from the pool
        existId = existPool.take();
        attributeGetSetMethod(existId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        // And releasing that existing ID for re-use
        existPool.offer(existId);       
    }
    } 


else if(command.getDataCriteria().equals(PDSLnPConstants.DATA_CRITERIA_NEW)) {
    try {
        System.out.println(command.getDataCriteria());
        // Getting new id from the pool
        newId = newPool.take();
        attributeGetSetMethod(newId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        // And releasing that new ID for re-use
        newPool.offer(newId);   
    }
    }
}
```

One weird thing that I have just noticed is- In the below `else if loop` if you see my above code in `run method` if the `command.getDataCriteria() is Previous` then also it gets entered in the `else if block(which is for New)` which shouldn't be happening right as I am doing a `.equals check`? Why this is happening?

```
else if(command.getDataCriteria().equals(PDSLnPConstants.DATA_CRITERIA_NEW)) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scenario under which you could get id = 0 (besides the possibility of undefined behaviour due to you not using synchronization) is when the id pool is exhausted (empty).  When that happens, the line:

```
id = idPool.getExistingId();
```

will fail with a NoSuchElementException.  In this case, the `finally` block will run:

```
idPool.releaseExistingId(id);
```

But `id` will still have its default value of `0` since the first line failed.  So you end up "releasing" `0` and adding it back to the id pool even though it was never in the pool to start with.  Then a later task could take `0` legitimately.

However, this should certainly print your exception in the catch block were it happening.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the suggestion. Yes I think that's what is happening I guess. And I don't need zero in any of my case. So how can I overcome this situation in my current code? Any thoughts?

Comment: But in my case I am always releasing the existing id so element should be there always in the idPool right?

Comment: @TechGeeky: Your idea of using an `ArrayBlockingQueue` (using `take()` instead of `remove()`) is exactly what I would suggest here.

Comment: And what about ThreadSafety issue? As multiple thread will be consuming same id right?

Comment: @TechGeeky: BlockingQueue is threadsafe, so two threads will never get the same id (unless the same id was in the queue twice to begin with).

Comment: Thanks Mark for the suggestion. I updated my question with the code that I am using currently and I am seeing some weird behavior that I have mentioned in my question. I think this is happening because of Multiple Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides (since Java 5) [Semaphore](http://javapapers.com/core-java/semaphores-using-java/) and I believe you are looking at [counting semaphore](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial-semaphores.html).

Comment: Thanks Pangea for the suggestion. Can you provide me an example basis on my code? That will be of great help to understand these things.